# Using Jasmine with iPhone Development?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, bdd, jasmine

I'm new to the **Jasmine Testing Framework**, I want to know how to use this for testing iPhone developments?

How can I integrate with Xcode and use for BDD testing? Will `Jasmine` only test my `JavaScript` code?? 
Then how can I use Jasmine in between my Xcode and call to `JavaScript` to verify that my `JavaScript` is valid?

I have already seen many links and examples but all are of these are testing JavaScript. I'm specifically asking only for iPhone. How do you communicate between JavaScript and an XCode Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to test Objective-C (iPhone) with Jasmine (JavaScript).

I have used the Appecelerator Titanium to develop an iPhone app -- it allows you to write code in JavaScript which is mapped to a native Objective-C interface. Its the only product so far that actually produces native code (as opposed to PhoneGap and others which run your JS code in an embedded webpage). I used jasmine to test my JavaScript code on the iPhone within my Titanium-built app and it worked great. Even setup was a breeze. I think it was this project that helped: https://github.com/guilhermechapiewski/titanium-jasmine

If you need to test Objective-C code, Cedar (by Pivotal Labs) is your best bet. You can find Cedar here: https://github.com/pivotal/cedar

Comment: Thanks. I already used this project.. and yes i need to test Javascript files which i am using in xcode. This was really a great experience to learn new thing. One more thing i used is to ingrate this with Instruments. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

[Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) is a javascript framework and is not easily used for testing objective-c code. However using JS to develop iphone apps is possible. If you are desperate to use Jasmine you should probably checkout [JSCocoa](http://inexdo.com/JSCocoa) If you just want to use a BDD framework you should look at [Cedar](http://github.com/pivotal/cedar) its similar to Jasmine.

Comment: Thanks but i had used titanium-Jasmine. But your answer also help me so +1.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Jasmine before for Javascript testing. I don't think it is possible to test XCode with it. It might however be possible to write tests in one language that could "compile" the source for the other language's tests. As Jasmine is Javascript based, i would think you'd need to run Javascript in XCode, is that even possible?